# New 6800/5500 watt generator, neutral connected to frame, replacing similar generator with floating neutral. Need help to rectify connecting to panel

Tags: generator, neutral

The original generator had a 3 wire cable connected to a 3 prong locking plug on the generator. It feeds a 240 volt 20 amp Stab lock breaker (with a fitted manual interlock to prevent feedback) on the main utility panel. Two wires are connected to main 240 volts and the white to neutral. This supplied 240/115 volt supplies to the home during emergencies.

The new generator I received has unfortunately got the neutral connected, via a yellow/green wire, to the frame/ground of the generator. Is there a way to somehow rectify this problem, outside the generator, that is not a costly venture?

After serving in the Navy for 31 years and other work I have used the backup power for years.

Comment: That's 240/120 unless you're losing 10V somewhere.

Comment: Is the neutral-ground link removable?  They often are, as people need to wire the generator to suit what it's powering, and any local laws.

Comment: If you actually have a 3-wire connection (hot/hot/neutral without ground) then you really should change it to a 4-wire connection. I find it extremely unlikely that a new generator would have an ungrounded receptacle.

Comment: And you should have this on a 30A circuit (and 10 AWG cable) or else you risk tripping past 4800W. And Stab Lok is usually not a good sign...

Comment: Also: Thank you for serving in the Navy. But it doesn't have anything to do with the question.

Comment: What make and model is the new generator, and is ripping the Stab-Lok panel out an option?  Also, how bent are you on "whole-house" backup power?

Comment: Thanks Simon. The neutral ground link was removed as per Champion's wiring instructions to change the generator to neutral floating.

Comment: Thanks Manasseh Katz and Three Phase The wiring and breaker sizes have been checked out for the loads that will be required and are more than sufficient. Extra heavy loads like the range will not be used. As l said to Simon, The champion BD100619 model connections at the generator terminal strip were changed as per champions  publicized instructions for their generators